# In line chartjs to render dataset dynamically from lines array. plz give suggest to solve

Tags: javascript, reactjs

data is like below

```
const data = [
   {name: 'A', value: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]},
   {name: 'B', value: [11,2,23,4,15,6,17]},
   {name: 'C', value: [9,22,3,14,5,61,7]},
]
```

here is the line chart code snippet

```
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import getRandomColor from "../functions";

export default function LineChartComponent({ data }) {
  const lines = data.map(val => {
    return [
      {
        label: val.name,
        data: val.value,
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
        borderColor: getRandomColor(),
        borderWidth: 3
      }
    ];
  });

  function getItem() {
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
      return lines[i];
    }
  }

  const database = {
    labels: ["Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"],

    datasets: getItem() //*** look here plz
  };

  return <Line data={database} height={300} width={400} />;
}
```

above snippet  `//*** look here plz` i want render data dynamically but my **getItem()** only render first element of lines array.
In `datasets: here should be render all of lines[0], lines[1], lines[2]` dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

It seems data.map returns array inside array... try to change this way:

```
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import getRandomColor from "../functions";

export default function LineChartComponent({ data }) {
  const datasets = data.map((val) => {
    return {
      label: val.name,
      data: val.value,
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),
      borderColor: getRandomColor(),
      borderWidth: 3,
    };
  });

  const database = {
    labels: ["Sat", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"],
    datasets
  };

  return <Line data={database} height={300} width={400} />;
}
```